# Screen Recording in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have two displays (one monitor, another projector) let's say `display1`, `display2`. I'm trying to show these to monitors on two QLabels `Label1` & `Label2`.
For this, I use the following code in QT.

```cpp
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QPixmap originalPixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
ui->label->setPixmap(originalPixmap);
```

this I made pushbutton specific i.e when I click on "start pushbutton" the above code will run and if I click on *"stop PushButton"* I'm clearing `label1` i.e  `ui->label->clear();`

By this I'm able to get the screenshots of images, but I want it to be live, so I thought to use QTimer to keep loading images onto the label and keep clearing it, but it doesn't seem working. Here's my code

```cpp
#include "ScreenCapture.h"
#include "ui_ScreenCapture.h"

ScreenCapture::ScreenCapture(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::ScreenCapture)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    CaptureTimer = new QTimer(this);
    CaptureTimer->setInterval(30);
    connect(CaptureTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(load_an_Image()));
    CaptureTimer->start();
}
void ScreenCapture::on_pbtn_start_clicked()
{
    load_an_Image();
}

void ScreenCapture::on_pbtn_stop_clicked()
{
    ui->label->clear();
}

void ScreenCapture::load_an_Image()
{
    on_pbtn_stop_clicked();
    QScreen* screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    QPixmap originalPixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
    ui->label->setPixmap(originalPixmap);
}
```

This isn't working as I'm getting the picture inside a picture i.e Picture

[image]

In this way, I thought to do for two different screens. So now my question is, is a better way of showing the screens live to `QLabels` and later record them and store it.

Comment: your timer is updating while you are in the timer code. use a 1 shot timer and restart it when you are done with the updates.

Comment: dgsomerton:: Thanks for Reply . but i didnt get ur point . can u be little more specific with wt u said .

Comment: you can try do call `QApplication::proccessEvents()` before the `grabWindow` - this way the window is redrawn after clearing before making the screenshot

Comment: Why you want `keep clearing`? Are you trying to capture screen except for `ScreenCapture` window itself?

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this overlay is that label clearing is not completed instantaneously (asynchronous), on the other hand you are taking the next shot just immediately, thus previous label pixmap appears and so on ...!
You need to refine your screen shots by suitable wait states, using another timer or any mechanism you find suitable.

The essense of the solution is to set a suitable interval between housekeeping work (clearing label ...etc.) and taking the screen shot.

for example:

```
ScreenCapture::ScreenCapture(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ScreenCapture)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    CaptureTimer=new QTimer(this);
    CaptureTimer->setInterval(200);
    connect(CaptureTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &ScreenCapture::on_pbtn_start_clicked);
    CaptureTimer->start();
}
void ScreenCapture::on_pbtn_start_clicked()
{
    ui->label->clear();
    QTimer::singleShot(20,this, &ScreenCapture::load_an_Image);
}
void ScreenCapture::on_pbtn_stop_clicked()
{
    ui->label->clear();
}

void ScreenCapture::load_an_Image()
{
    screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    QPixmap originalPixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
    ui->label->setPixmap(originalPixmap);
}
```

Comment: Can't see any difference, Could you explain why `clear()` is necessary?

Comment: @Jiu Can't see any difference compared to what! have you looked at Qt [Screenshot Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html) ? in the example if you set the delay to 0 sec, you cant check _Hide this window_ .. and if you take a series of shots you will see the overlay!

Comment: @Jiu, _why `clear()` is necessary?_ ... look again to question , OP stated **requirement**: _keep loading images onto the label and keep clearing it_!

Comment: I know the example, the key point is the example used `hide()` before capture if you want to capture without window itself. Because `capture` needs to do until windows completely invisible. But adding `clear()` does not change the program result. I think should put the well meaningful code as an answer.

Comment: @Jiu, The answer works as expected. You better spare your time to test the example WELL and then the OP code and the answer code.

Comment: I did run OP & your post, I consider the Qt Screenshot example as the right way to capture, but it did not make the process _be live_ as the requirement.

Comment: @Jiu, Just try to modify the example to make series of shots automatically (while hiding window) ... then you realize you need 2 timers, one for automation, second to hide the window exactly as in example code. The purpose of an answer in SO is just to clarify a concept NOT to provide code service ... The OP said he wants to clear the label ... he does not want to hide the window .. we don't know his purpose and we don't make assumptions!

Comment: I tried [that](https://github.com/arkceajin/QtDemos/blob/master/ScreenCapture/screencapture.h), does not need the second timer. but it can't prevent the windows blink. He said clear the label and _but it doesn't seem working_. And he mentioned he doesn't want the _picture inside a picture_, using `clear` is simply removing the part of contents of the picture, the frame still remains inside the picture. So until he clarifies what he wants, I don't think `clear` is the right way.